# What is the grammar behind this type of sentence structure?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> *Taylor described this danger to the Huffington Post; "I see clients for whom food has become problematic, and they struggle to go out and
> not have food be the key element of all social interaction: what they
> eat, when they ate, when they are going to eat again."*

I know what Taylor means is that if some of her clients don't see food as the key element, they feel reluctant to go out. How to explain this usage of two "negatives?"

Comment: No. Taylor described this danger to the Huffington Post: "I see clients for whom food has become problematic.  When ... if ... they go out and socialise, it is a struggle not to have food as the most important topic for discussion –  what they eat, when they ate, when they are going to eat again."

Comment: Taylor means the opposite of what you (the OP) think: the clients want food to be unimportant when they go out, but they struggle to achieve this. They don't want to think about food.

Comment: Double negatives need to share a clause to fight each other. "If I don't X, I don't want to do Y" has **no** double negatives and **is not** a problem.

Comment: It is a bit unusual to have  a negative infinitive _to not think of food_ as the complement of _struggle_. Since the complementizer _to_ is back with _struggle_, one conjoined clause away, it sounds kind of funny (on paper, at least). In speech, I think it would be disambiguated by presentation. As usual

Comment: Where are the 2 negatives? I only saw one.